# How to log `catch_backtrace` to a file

Tags: logging, julia, traceback

I’d like to catch any errors and log the error message with full traceback to a log file for me to review. My implementation is based on this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232715/how-to-capture-the-full-stack-trace-when-logging-in-julia), currently I get the desired result in my STDOUT, but the log file traceback contains lots of `Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000121cc6b5e` which isn’t helpful . Below is a minimal example:

```
using LoggingExtras, Logging
global_logger(FileLogger("log_file.log"))
# few functions so we get traceback
function bar(b)
    error("Failed with b:$b")
end
function foo(a)
    bar(a)
end
function run(c)
    foo(c)
end
try
    run(2)
catch e
    @error "failure" exception = (e, catch_backtrace())
end
```

gives a meaningful message in the STDOUT

```
┌ Error: failure
│   exception =
│    Failed with b:2
│    Stacktrace:
│     [1] error(s::String)
│       @ Base ./error.jl:33
│     [2] bar(b::Int64)
│       @ Main /private/tmp/log_problem/ex.jl:6
│     [3] foo(a::Int64)
│       @ Main /private/tmp/log_problem/ex.jl:10
│     [4] run(c::Int64)
│       @ Main /private/tmp/log_problem/ex.jl:14
│     [5] top-level scope
│       @ /private/tmp/log_problem/ex.jl:17
│     [6] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
│       @ Base ./Base.jl:418
│     [7] exec_options(opts::Base.JLOptions)
│       @ Base ./client.jl:292
│     [8] _start()
│       @ Base ./client.jl:495
└ @ Main /private/tmp/log_problem/ex.jl:19
```

But in `log_file.log` I get

```
┌ Error: failure
│   exception = (ErrorException("Failed with b:2"), Union{Ptr{Nothing}, Base.InterpreterIP}[Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000121cc6b5e, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010a7ed743, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010a7ed7af, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010a7ed80f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010a7ed835, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010896b4a0, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001089848df, Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000108982e26, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010898306a, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010898341c, Base.InterpreterIP in top-level CodeInfo for Main at statement 1, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010899e49f, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010899e242, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010899f515, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001220732fa, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010896b4a0, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001221b85f5, Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000121d75a85, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010896b4a0, Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000121e39314, Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000121683dff, Ptr{Nothing} @0x0000000121683f68, Ptr{Nothing} @0x000000010896b4a0, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001089c1d32, Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000001089c1c23])
└ @ Main /private/tmp/log_problem/ex.jl:19
```

How can I get the log file to contain the same information as the stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FileLogger`](https://julialogging.github.io/reference/loggingextras/#LoggingExtras.FileLogger-Tuple%7BAny%7D) uses a [`SimpleLogger`](https://julialogging.github.io/reference/logging/#Logging.SimpleLogger) internally, which, as the name suggests, is a simple logger without any formatting. You could instead use a [`FormatLogger`](https://julialogging.github.io/reference/loggingextras/#LoggingExtras.FormatLogger) to format exceptions the way you like it.

If you want the same formatting as in the Julia REPL you can use the same logger, which is the [`ConsoleLogger`](https://julialogging.github.io/reference/logging/#Logging.ConsoleLogger), but then you need to handle the opening of the file yourself and pass the open writeable `IO` to the constructor.